# f(x) is a function such that $\lim_{x\to0} f(x)/x=1$

Tags: limits

$f(x)$ is a function such that $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=1$$ if

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x(1+a\cos(x))-b\sin(x)}{f(x)^3}=1$$

Find $a$ and $b$

Can I assume $f(x)$ to be $\sin(x)$ since $\sin$ satisfies the given condition?

Comment: Simple answer, no!

Comment: You really shouldn't assume $f(x)$ is $\sin(x)$ because you have not shown that $a$ and $b$ are unique and irrespective of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**. You may use the standard Taylor series expansions, as $x \to 0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\cos x&=1-\frac{x^2}2+O(x^4)\\
\sin x&=x-\frac{x^3}6+O(x^4)
\end{align}
$$ giving
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{x(1+a\cos x)-b\sin x}{(f(x))^3}&=\frac{(1+a-b) x+\frac16 (-3 a+b) x^3+O(x^5)}{(f(x))^3}
\\\\&=\frac{(1+a-b) x+\frac169 (-3 a+b) x^3+O(x^5)}{x^3(1+\epsilon(x))^3}
\end{align}
$$ where, as $x \to 0$, we have used $f(x)=x(1+\epsilon(x))$ with $\epsilon(x) \to 0$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: What did you do with the denominator

Comment: Please, see my edit.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this does not answer the question!

Comment: @almagest Sorry, I did not read correctly the question. Let's say it is a *hint* to answer the first part of the question: "find $a$ and $b$..."

Comment: Now what should i do

Comment: To vanish the first term in $x$ gives $b=a+1$, then you have to solve  $\frac{1}{6} (-3 a+b)=1$, you find $a=-\frac52$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa but why is the coefficient of x = 0

Comment: If not the limit doesn't exist, if not you get something like $\frac{(1+a-b)x}{x^3}$ which is bad as $x \to 0$...

Comment: @OlivierOloa why is coefficient of $x^3$ equal to one

Comment: Because you are asked to obtain the value $1$ for the limit.

Comment: By changing the denominator you are assuming f(x)=x aren't you

Comment: Not exactly, we have $f(x)=x+x\epsilon(x)$, that is $x$ plus something small before $x$... because $\lim f(x)/x=1$ means $f(x)/x-1=\epsilon(x)$ with $\epsilon(x) \to 0$, then multiplying throughout by $x$ gives $f(x)=x+x\epsilon(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite $$A=\frac{x(1+a\cos(x))-b\sin(x)}{f(x)^3}= \frac{x(1+a\cos(x))-b\sin(x)}{x^3}\times\Big(\frac{x}{f(x)}\Big)^3$$ and now, as Olivier Oloa answered, use Taylor expansions.

Whichever could be $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=L$ (except $0$ or $\infty$), you could find the conditions you want for  $\lim_{x\to0} A=M$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: we have:  $\dfrac{1+a\cos x}{x^2} - \dfrac{b}{\sin^2 x} \to 1$, and rewrite $\dfrac{b}{\sin^2 x} = \dfrac{b}{x^2}\cdot \dfrac{x^2}{\sin^2 x}$ then the limit on the left equals $\dfrac{1+a\cos x - b}{x^2} = 1$, this means you can assume L'hopitale rule meaning: $1 + a - b = 0$, and differentiate both numerator and denominator to get another equation and solve for $a, b$.

Comment: How did you write the first step

Answer (score 1):

Since $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=1$, we have
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{f(x)}
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{\frac{f(x)}{x}}
=\frac{1}{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}}
=\frac{1}{1}=1.$$
Now, by using L'Hopital's rule, we have
\begin{align}
1&=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x(1+a\cos(x))-b\sin(x)}{f(x)^3}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0}\left[\frac{x^3}{f(x)^3}\cdot\frac{x(1+a\cos(x))-b\sin(x)}{x^3}\right]\\
&=\left(\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x}{f(x)}\right)^3\cdot
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x(1+a\cos(x))-b\sin(x)}{x^3}\\
&\stackrel{\rm H}{=}
1^3\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1+a\cos(x)-ax\sin(x)-b\cos(x)}{3x^2}\tag{1}\\
&\stackrel{\rm H}{=}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-a\sin(x)-a\sin(x)-ax\cos(x)+b\sin(x)}{6x}\\
&\stackrel{\rm H}{=}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-2a\cos(x)-a\cos(x)+ax\sin(x)+b\cos(x)}{6}\\
&=\frac{-3a+b}{6}\tag{2}.
\end{align}
By $(1)$, we have to force the limit of the numerator to be zero, so $1+a-b=0$. Also, by $(2)$ we naturally get $-3a+b=6$. Hence we conclude that
$a=-\frac{5}{2}$ and $b=-\frac{3}{2}$.